# Paypalアカウントの状態確認

Tags: paypal

Adaptive Paymentsの連鎖支払でお金を受け取るにはプレミア会員になる必要があるらしいですが、対象会員のステータス（プレミア会員なのか）をAPIから確認することはできるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetVerifiedStatus APIでPayPalアカウントのアカウントのステータスを取得できますよ。
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/